# ERROR: 'EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'RowIndex'

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am doing an update button for a GridView and I am getting this error for RowIndex: EventArgs does not contain any definition for RowIndex

```
string connectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.db;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
id = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["id"].Value.ToString();
```

How can I fix it? Thank you for any suggestion!

Comment: Can you start by showing what the event signature looks like where this is being called? That error is obvious itself, you're trying to get the current row index from `e` in which is declared as `EventArgs` and it doesn't have the definition. You could get that index by  `DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs` or `DataGridViewCell.RowIndex` (if you have the cell you want) or if you want the current `DataGridViewCell`, you could do: `dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex` to get that row index.

Comment: How am I doing this specifying Cells["id"] or any different Cells I need?

Answer (score 0):

your function should be like this "protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).